What happens if you defeat the Grafted Scion in the beginning of Elden Ring?
In the beginning of Elden Ring when you leave the Chapel of Anticipation, you’ll find a Grafted Scion boss. This is meant to be a scripted thing, and you are supposed to die here so you can get to the tutorial area.
What happens if you kill it instead? Is there anything through the fog gate it’s guarding, or does that just lead to where you go when you’re meant to die, as a failsafe?

If you manage to kill the Grafted Scion at the beginning of the game, you'll gain the following rewards:

3,200 runes
The Ornamental Straight Sword
The Golden Beast Crest Shield

The fog gate you mention disappears once the boss fight is over. Moving further past the boss area, you'll be able to pick up a couple of Nascent Butterflies. The area then opens up a bit to a plateau once you walk across a bridge. When you've reached the opposite end of the plateau, you'll see an item on the ground. Approaching the item will cause the rocky overhang you're standing on to collapse, causing you to fall to your death. This item is not obtainable, and serves only to get you to stand there in order to fall.
Dying after defeating the Grafted Scion in the area surrounding it (and beyond) will take you to the tutorial area that you mentioned. This death will not incur a loss of the runes you worked so hard to get vs the Grafted Scion.
I did not try going further away from the Grafted Scion to see if dying would not warp you to the tutorial area or not, but I have to imagine all deaths after defeating this boss in the area will take you to the tutorial area, as otherwise the game's flow would be interrupted.

Do you obtain any runes from killing the Scion? If so, do you lose them all when falling off the overhang, resulting in losing them forever?

@Daemons 1) Yes, I've edited that in. 2) No, you retain them.
